# How to find the maximum number of independent pairwise comparisons between groups

Tags: categorical-data, paired-comparisons, combinatorics

I have the following situation:
Consider a dataset that is comprised of a number of factor levels

```
x = gl(5,1)
> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
> Levels: 1 2 3 4 5
```

I want to obtain the number of true independent pairwise comparisons (no pseudo-replication) of a distance matrix between those factor levels. Ignoring reciprocal direction (so $\ A-B == B-A $ ), the number of possible pairwise independent comparisons should be exactly $\ 2 * n -1 $ out of all possible combinations $\ n^2 $

The **problem**:

In addition to the pairwise comparison between each level, they are each individually element of another group that limits the total number of comparisons possible.

So for instance:

```
data.frame(x = gl(12,1), y = letters[1:3])
> x y
> 1 a
> 2 b
> 3 c
> 4 a
> 5 b
> 6 c
> 7 a
> 8 b
> 9 c
> 10 a
> 11 b
> 12 c
```

A level in column `x` can only have pairwise differences with values that have a different level in column `y`
So the pairwise difference $\ 1-2 $ is allowed, but the comparison between $\ 1-4 $ is not (as both have the same level `a` in column `y`)

- How do I obtain the total number of possible unique pairwise comparisons limited by membership to a group?
- Is there a clever way (in `R`) how to specifically subsample the allowed comparisons? Right now I am taking the super-diagonal (diag + 1) of a distance matrix with multiple permutations to approximate truly independent comparisons. For different group ownership I would need to implement another permutation step that takes a random element out of all values belonging to a group. This double-permutation seems somewhat inefficient to me...

---

**EDIT:**
Some further explanation seems to be necessary (see comments)
My data is ordered in semi-distance matrices (ignoring the diagonal) and I want to sample independent comparisons from that matrix. I don't / can not compute all possible pairwise comparisons as this would be costly. Longacre and Scott demonstrated that that sampling only the off-diagonal of a number of permuted matrices is linearly correlated with the true number of all possible pairwise comparisons ( but see https://newtraell.cs.uchicago.edu/files/tr_authentic/TR-2005-13.pdf ). Essentially it works by permuting the distance matrix (the order of values in $\ n x m $ and taking the off-diagonal (n-1) a specific number of times.

But I am also open to other suggestions how to efficiently get a representation of the variation within all pairwise comparisons.

My particular application is the following:
I have a number of distance matrices $\ n x m $ for a single group **G**. I want to draw the minimal number of independent pairwise comparisons as possible. However each individual element $\ n $ alongs to a group **H** which limits the number of possible pairwise comparisons. How many are there and how do I most efficiently get the number of pairwise comparisons that are *(a)* in different sites $\ n $ and *(b)* belong to different groups as defined by **H**?

Comment: Forgive me; where does 2n-1 come from?

Comment: It is based on research by Angelika Longacre ( http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219720005001600 ), who prooved that there are exactly 2n-1 linearly independent pairwise comparisons

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "pseudo-replication," the linked article is behind a paywall, and the related technical report noted as a reference in the article is not available. It's not clear what $n$ represents in the available abstract of the linked article.The standard formula for the number of unordered pairs among $n$ cases is $n \choose 2$. Note that the $2n-1$ formula does not work with with $n=3$ cases {a,b,c}, where there are 3 unique pairwise comparisons ({a,b},{a,c},{b,c}) rather than 5 as your formula suggests. Please explain more precisely what you mean.

Comment: Yes, the $\ 2n-1 $ formula was thought to be applied to a semi-distance matrix and it works by taking the off-diagonal $\ N $ number of times from the same permuted matrix. It is essentially a shortcut and Longacre et al. claimed to have shown that only $\ 2n-1 $ measurements would be need to reflect all possible comparisons $\ \binom{n}{2} $ (whose computation can be costly). Here is an accessible technical report describing their findings: https://newtraell.cs.uchicago.edu/research/publications/techreports/TR-2005-13 . Will add further explanation question as well

Comment: I've looked at the tech report. As far as I can tell, it basically says that if you have made $2n$ observations (in $n$ sets of pairs) then you have $2n-1$ degrees of freedom. Yes, you can construct any additional pairwise comparison among these $2n$ observations in terms of $2n-1$ values, but you still have $2n \choose 2$ such comparisons. Note that the paper behind the paywall has only received 7 citations in Google Scholar in 10 years. It might be better to rephrase your question with more details about your own problem (the nature of the distance matrices, what $n$ and $m$ represent, etc.)